# Prove that there exists bipartite graph with this degree sequence: $(3,3,3,3,3,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

How do I prove that there exists (or does not exist) bipartite graph with this degree sequence: $(3,3,3,3,3,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6)$ ?

The sum of the degree sequence is even and simplfied it looks like this: $(1,1,1,1,1,1)$ => it's a degree sequence of a graph.

The simplified degree sequence might suggest that it could be bipartite graph, but I have no idea how to prove it.

Comment: From your comments, I am not sure if it being bipartite is required or if you think that would be a good place to look. Could you clarify?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sum of the degrees is $68$, so there must be $34$ edges. If the graph is bipartite, the sum of the degrees of the vertices in each part must be $34$. Show that this is impossible: there is no way to split the numbers $3,3,3,3,3,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6$ into two sets, each summing to $34$. HINT: At least one of the sets must have four or more vertices of degree $6$; why?

Comment: Just to note, this is a necessary condition of being graphic. The Gale-Ryser Theorem provides conditions for two degree sequences (one for each part of the vertex set) to be realizable as a bipartite graph. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gale%E2%80%93Ryser_theorem

Comment: Nice, I think the following argument as to why $34$ cant be made is easier. The side without $5$ adds up to a multiple of $3$, which $34$ is not.

Comment: @dREaM: That is indeed quicker and easier; very nice. (Well, unless you happen for some reason to see the other argument first. :-))

Comment: Thanks guys, also @dREaM very neat!

Comment: @Mykybo: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 6):

The sum of degrees on one side needs to equal the sum of degrees on the other side. But there’s only one number here which is not a multiple of $3$, so no matter how the numbers are distributed, the subset which contains the $5$ cannot add up to a multiple of $3$, while the side without the $5$ has to be a multiple of $3$, so no such graph exists. Hope it helps.