# Is there a bipartite graph with degrees of vertices $(3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,5,6,6,6,6)$

Tags: graph-theory

I have no idea how to check this?

Could someone give a hint?

Comment: Have you tried building a graph whose vertices have those degrees?

Answer (score 3):

**[Other than this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1600289/prove-that-there-exists-bipartite-graph-with-this-degree-sequence-3-3-3-3-3-5)**:

---

The sum of degrees on one side needs to equal the sum of degrees on the other side. But there’s only one number here which is not a multiple of $3$, so no matter how the numbers are distributed, the subset which contains the $5$ cannot add up to a multiple of $3$, while the side without the $5$ has to be a multiple of $3$, so no such graph exists.

Comment: This is a much simpler argument than the existing answer to the duplicate. You should probably post it there too (or instead?).

Comment: @HenningMakholm Thank you. Should I post it there as well? Do you it is a good idea?(in the sense that it already has an accepted answer).

Comment: An accepted answer should not prevent you from posting a _better_ answer. (There may be some who frown of posting the same answer twice to different questions, reaping rep from it twice -- depending on how much you care about that you may either delete this one, or possibly flag for a moderator to _merge_ this entire question with the duplicate, which will also make this answer end up there).